# Can a QSFP28 port break out to 4 SFP+ ports to separate hosts?

Tags: fortigate, sfp, dell

I apologize in advance because I suspect this is already covered. I've read some of the posts and I suspect the answer is "it depends on the vendors involved" or just "no".

I'm looking at the Dell S4128T-ON and I'm new to SFP/SFP+/SFP28/QSFP/QSFP28 tech. The reseller is saying that it's a no - the quad breakout is intended to all to go the same host.

I have two switches, each with two QSFP28 ports. I was going to dedicate one port to link the switches and the other to connect to two ports on a Fortigate 100F firewall via SPF+ (so two of the quad cable connections would be unused - switchA to FortiGateA & switchB to FortiGateB - active/passive HA for firewalls).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most devices, that is possible. Check the manual for splitting a QSFP28 port into four SFP28 or SFP+ interfaces.

The [datasheet](https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/dell-emc-networking-S4100-series-spec-sheet.pdf) specifically shows *28 10GbT and 8 SFP+* for 10G and lists a *40GbE, 4x10GbE, QSFP+ to 4xSFP+, passive DAC*.

According to the [user guide](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/networking-s4148f-on/os10-enterprise-user-guide-10.4.0e-r3-pub/breakout-auto-configuration), using `feature auto-breakout` should automatically detect a breakout cable and use split ports:

> Breakout auto-configuration
>
> ---
>
> You can globally enable front-panel Ethernet ports to automatically
> detect SFP pluggable media in a QSFP+ or QSFP28 port. The port
> autoconfigures breakout interfaces for media type and speed. For
> example, if you plug a 40G direct attach cable (DAC) with 4x10G
> far-side transceivers into a QSFP28 port, the port autoconfigures in
> 10g-4x Interface-breakout mode.
>
> RJ-45 ports and ports that are members of a port group do not support
> breakout auto-configuration. Breakout auto-configuration is disabled
> by default.
>
> **Enable breakout auto-configuration**
>
> `OS10(config)# feature auto-breakout`
>
> **Display breakout auto-configuration**
>
> Before you plug a cable in
> Ethernet port 1/1/25:
>
> `OS10# show interface status`
>
> ```
>                 ------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 Port       Description  Status Speed Duplex Mode Vlan Tagged-Vlans
>                 ------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 Eth 1/1/1               down   0     auto    -
>                 Eth 1/1/2               down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/25              down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/29              down   0     auto    A    1    -
> ```
>
> After you enter `feature auto-breakout` and plug a breakout cable in
> Ethernet port 1/1/25:
>
> `OS10# show interface status`
>
> ```
>                 ------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 Port       Description  Status Speed Duplex Mode Vlan Tagged-Vlans
>                 ------------------------------------------------------------------
>                 Eth 1/1/1               down   0     auto    -
>                 Eth 1/1/2               down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/25:1            down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/25:2            down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/25:3            down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/25:4            down   0     auto    A    1    -
>                 Eth 1/1/29              down   0     auto    A    1    -
> ```

There is no mention that all breakout ports need to link to the same host nor would that make much sense - it would imply a LAG trunk, largely negating the reason for a port breakout.

Comment: Yeah, I call BS on the reseller. Once the port is broken out, it's 4 ports like any other.